# Multivariable Calculus, circles, maximum and minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, circles, maxima-minima

Determine the minimum and maximum values of $f(x, y) = 2x^2 −3y^2 + 40y −6$ on the circle
$x^2 + y^2 = 25$.

I don't understand what the question is asking me to do? What does it mean by "maximum and minimum values...on the circle..."?

Comment: Imo the the question is saying find the maximum and minimum of the function subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2=25$

Comment: If it means that the equation of the circle is a constraint, what would I need to do to start solving this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks the maximum and minimum values of the function $$f(x,y)=2x^2-3y^2+40y-6$$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2-25=0$

From the Lagrangian$:$
$$L(x,y,\lambda)=(2x^2-3y^2+40y-6)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-25)$$
Find all first order partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x^2-3y^2+40y-6)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-25)=2x(\lambda+2)$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2x^2-3y^2+40y-6)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-25)=2\lambda y-6y+40$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x^2-3y^2+40y-6)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-25)=x^2+y^2-25$$
Now solve these three simulations liner equations that we got after taking partial derivatives. The solutions that will come are $$(x,y)=(3,4) ,(-3,4) ,(0,5) ,(0,-5)$$
$$\begin{align*}
f(3,4)=124\\
f(-3,4)=124\\
f(0,5)=119\\
f(0,-5)=-281
\end{align*} $$
Hence the maximum value of the function subject to the given constraint is $\boxed{124}$ and minimum for the same is $\boxed{-281}$

Comment: Do you know of any Youtube videos that I can watch to learn the material covered in the answer you gave?

Comment: @mku I don't exactly know the videos but I guess that there should be many of them. Just search up Lagrange multipliers and watch the video that you think is the best.